# Ajax call error during Rally sdk custom dashboard developement

Tags: extjs, rally, code-rally

I'm getting 403 exception when I make an ajax call to jenkins api call to get the build details from Rally sdk custom html interface.

```
        //Ajax api call to jenkins
        var blink ="https://[jenkinshost]/job/Appdev/job/TestProject/api/json";
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: blink, 
            method :'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            withCredentials: true,  
            headers : { 
                'Authorization': 'Basic dsasfsfxfhfj',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            },
            success: function(response){
                var backToJs=JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                    console.log('resp data-',backToJs);
                    //console.log(backToJs['QueryResult'].Results);

            },
            failure: function(response) {
                console.log('jenkins-ajax call failure');
            }
        });
```

ajax call error-

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:  No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.  Origin 'https://rally1.rallydev.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your .htaccess file on both domains this string:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

And try to find more information about cross-domain requests.

Comment: thanks for reply i have added below parameters in the header still i'm getting same error 403.
 headers : { 
                'Authorization': 'Basic dsasfsfxfhfj',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
            },

Comment: This is a CORS error because your jenkins instance is not configured to allow cross domain requests.  Your app code will probably just work once you get your CORS configuration enabled as above on your jenkins server.

Comment: @Kyle thanks for reply i will figure out jenkins CORS configuration  thing and come back.